# How do I destroy the "red blocks" in dungeons in Terraria

Tags: terraria-mobile

I use the app version and this "red block" (I don't know why it's called that) but it's in the dungeons with the Blood Crawlers and Hearts, and it won't break.

How can I break the "red block?"

Comment: I think you'll need to be more specific with what you are talking about. There are no red blocks at all in the Dungeon as far as I know. In fact there aren't any blocks called "red blocks". Blood Crawlers and Crimson Hearts are in the Crimson, which is another thing altogether...

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about [Crimstone Blocks](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimstone_Block).

You can break them with at least a [**Deathbringer Pickaxe**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Deathbringer_Pickaxe) (or [Nightmare Pickaxe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nightmare_Pickaxe) in corrupted worlds).